# Convergence test for series

Tags: calculus

> Let  $\space \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \space \left | \frac{\cos(n\pi)}{n+1}\right |$. Does this series converge or not?

The serie is valid for the natural numbers, so it can be writen as $\space \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \space  \frac{\left |\cos(n\pi)\right |}{n+1}$.

One knows that $\space 0\leq\left |\cos(n\pi)\right |\leq 1$. By using the asymptotic concept, one can say that the leader terms of the top and bottom of the fraction are $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}$.

And so, the original serie is equivalent to this one
$$\space \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \space \frac{1}{n}$$

that is a $p$ series, where $p\leq 1$ and so diverges, and also the original series. This is correct? Thanks.

Comment: You need to show that a series which is less than the given series diverges to conclude that the given series diverges. Here $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is greater than the given series, not less.

Comment: Note that $|\cos(n\pi)|=1$ for $n$ even and $\cos(n\pi)=0$ for n odd. Use this to do the reasoning.

Comment: @MilindHegde Actually, it is equal, but that's because $\cos n\pi = \pm 1$

Comment: @martin.koeberl $\cos n\pi = -1$ for $n$ odd, and $1$ for $n$ even.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Oh yeah, always get this wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, I did not notice the $n\pi$. Thank you for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $|\cos(n\pi)| = 1\;\; \forall n,\;$ your series is equivalent to:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\left|(-1)^n\right|}{(n + 1)} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n+1} $$

You're "spot on" with respect to comparing your given series to the harmonic series: $\;\;\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac 1n,\;$ but since $\;\dfrac 1{n+1} \lt \dfrac 1n,\;$ you can note that

$$\sum_{\color{blue}{\bf n = 1}}^\infty \frac 1{n+1} \quad = \quad \sum_{\color{blue}{\bf n = 2}}\frac 1n$$ and so, save for one term, your series **is** the harmonic series, and diverges just as does the "strict" harmonic series.

If you want a tighter argument, you can use the ***[limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)*** of your series and the "strict" harmonic series to prove your series diverges.

$$\text{Put, say}\;\;a_n = \dfrac 1{n+1},\;\;b_n = \dfrac 1n \iff
\dfrac{a_n}{b_n} = \dfrac{1/(n+1)}{1/n} = \dfrac n{n+1}$$

$$\text{Then we have}\quad\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac n{n+1} = 1 < \infty$$

Since the harmonic series given by $\sum b_n$ diverges, so too does your series.

Comment: $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n+1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n}$ so the comparison can be done.

Comment: Indeed, @martycohen I'm just suggesting the the limit comparison test readily reveals and establishes exactly what we, and the OP, already know: that the comparison with the series is valid.

Comment: It is rather senseless to compare the harmonic series to the harmonic series, don't you agree? It is also senseless to write $\sum \frac 1{n+1}\color{red}{<}\sum \frac 1n $ when neither of those sums is defined.

Comment: @amWhy Still, I think one should merely say that $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ is the harmonic series save term, so it diverges. No more, no less.

Comment: Hand wave? There is no hand waving. The terms are the harmonic series shifted by one. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

No. Since the p-series you've considered was only an upper bound for the series, the fact that it diverges to infinity tells you nothing.

Comment: actually, since the original series is $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left|\cos n\pi\right|/(n + 1)$, the series is actually $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left|(-1)^n\right|/(n + 1) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}1/(n + 1)$, which diverges because it is just a shifted harmonic series. The reasoning wasn't totally rigorous in getting to the end, but by comparison to $1/n$ the series does indeed diverge.

Comment: Ahh yes. I was concentrating on the method and not the actual question but you are completely correct.

Comment: @john you are right. By using a graph simulator I could see that the sequence corresponding to the p-serie expression is greater than the sequence of the original serie, for all natural numbers. So the direct comparion test doesn't work. Maybe the limit comparation test? I will try.Thanks

Comment: As has been suggested by others, first consider what values $\cos (n\pi)% takes for integer values of $n$. This should simplify the problem greatly.